# Why does an <input> element lose its left/right margins when given a width?

Tags: html, google-chrome, css

The following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form>
    <input type=text>
</form>
```

Produces the following box model in Chrome:

[image: box model no width]

However, if the input type is styled with a width:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form>
    <input type=text style="width: 100px;">
</form>
```

The left and right margin are removed:

[image]

Why is this?

Comment: Looks like user-agent chrome is disabled if styles are applied.

Comment: Reproduced in jsfiddle using chrome as well: http://jsfiddle.net/Jh9ng/

Good question. I made in jsfiddle because the imgur is blocked at my work.

Comment: You can see it better here: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/Jh9ng/1

Comment: That question definitely deserves a +1 ... good one, and I've no idea why, although I'm sure there's a very logic explanation I just can't think of.

Comment: Not happening in FF so probably not in the spec, just a Chrome bug or special behaviour. Maybe it's reserving a bit of space for the glow you get when input validation fails?

Comment: @isherwood: Isn't your first comment true for most if not all user agents and a variety of styles anyway?

Comment: Couldn't say. I've not encountered a situation where one style affects another in this manner.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"The purpose of intrinsic margins is to try to prevent adjacent controls from butting up against one another. Especially with rounded controls this looks terrible. The reason you see the values change is that we only set intrinsic margins when we think it won't disrupt the layout of the page. **If the author specifies an explicit height/width on the control, then we assume the designer is needing pixel-precise control, and so we turn the margins off to avoid disrupting the page layout.**"

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128306#c20

Comment: amazing. thanks for sharing deep knowledge. looks like it's a Chrome specific thing then.

Comment: The good news is that if you want to remove just the intrinsic margins without touching *any* other styles, you can still set the `margin` property by itself.